# explanation of why interphase occurs in polymers

Tags: polymers

Im new to chemistry network of stackexchange so please be kind to me!
I heard that interphase is created in clay polymer for 2 reasons.
one of the reasons is the insoluble part of the polymer and the second reason is for second TG.
can some one please explain how these 2 factors cause interphase? or can you recommend articles?
thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean interface? What is "TG"?

Comment: Wlcome to chemistry.SE! To me [interphase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interphase) is a biological process. Are you asking about something like a [suspension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_(chemistry))?